# Testing ActionResult<T> when BadRequest() is returned

Tags: c#, nunit, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to build a unit test around a controller using .NET Core's Web API. I'm running into an issue when creating a test for a negative scenario where the response should be a `BadRequest(string)`:

### ThingController.cs

```
[HttpPost("thing/{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
public async Task<ActionResult<Thing>> Add(string id, [FromBody] Thing thing)
{
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
  {
    return BadRequest("Must provide Thing ID");
  }

  return this.thingRepo.AddThing(id, thing);
}
```

### ThingControllerTests.cs

```
[Test]
public async Task AddThing_FailOnEmptyId() {
  var mockRepo = new Mock<IThingRepository>();
  var testController = new ThingController(mockRepo.Object);
  var result = await testController.AddThing("", this.validThing);

  Assert.That(result, Is.InstanceOf<BadRequestObjectResult>());
}
```

In this case, the value of `result` is always `Thing` where I expect it to be `BadRequestObjectResult`.

Some additional details:

- I've verified that the test exercises the correct branch and performs `return BadRequest("Must provide Thing ID")` like I expected.
- If I change the return type from `Task<ActionResult<T>>` to `Task<ActionResult>` the test passes like I expect.
- After reading the docs on the Microsoft site [Controller action return types - ActionResult T type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2#actionresultt-type) I think I have the code itself correct enough for this test.

Is there a specific cast I need to perform to get the proper type? Am I missing a detail about NUnit that will make this work?

Comment: I don't know if duplicate questions are visible or not to others searching. If they are though, the answer to this was that `result` contains two values - `Result` and `Value`, where `Result` is the original `ActionResult` and `Value` is of type `T`. So your test can use each of those properties to see what has happened.

Comment: As the type is still relatively new I do not think much documentation about testing it has been done. I only found it because I look at the source code repository regularly.